# Multiple Push-Registrations for one Channel

Tags: c#, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Can someone give me a reason why I can have mor than one registraiontId for a push-notification-channel? What's the purpose on this?

I have read so many articles about handling push-notifications (I use azure services), but I didn't find a reason. I know, the channel can change over time and then I need to change the channel on my registration-id per device on my backend).

Following method seems to be loading more than one registration. Why?

```
await HubClient.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync("<pnsHandle>", 100)
```

Or in other words: What's the main difference between the channel and a registration?

I am a little bit confused about that... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Channel vs Registration**

The *"channel"* is the handle between a device and the corresponding push notification service (e.g. APNS for iOS).  Think of a "channel" as representing the device.

The *"registration"*, or to be more precise the "Azure Notification Hub registration", contains data to *address* and *manage* devices that can receive push notifications via a channel.

You can only have *one channel* for a specific app on a specific device, but you can have *multiple registrations* for the same app on that device via that channel.

**Why Have Multiple Registrations?**

You don't have to have multiple registrations per channel.  But, below are some reasons why you might decide to.

One use case is, for example, to have **multiple template registrations** for one device with **specific templates** for different notifications. You can distinguish these registrations by tags then.

For example, one device/channel might have specific template registrations for the following notifications for a social network app:

- Friend request (template parameters: *friend name)*
- Chat message (template parameters: *sender name, chat message)*
- Status update (template parameters: *friend name, status update)*

Another use case would be to have one registration for each service that wants to send push notifications to your app.

You can only have one channel for a specific app on a specific device, but you can have multiple registrations for the same app on that device, where each registration is managed and used by another service.